# jQuery - find html element with server generated id

Tags: jquery, html

I have this element I need to find in the DOM with the id of:

```
ctl00_Spwebpartmanager1_g_0dff8583_314d_412f_8be7_ad019dd61cf3_ctl00__socialSecurityNumber
```

How do I get a hold of it?

Comment: I think you can use Client ID read about more but it was in .net but you can refer this which has some idea. http://net4.ccs.neu.edu/home/dhruven/story/index.htm?url=../experiments/experiment12/experiment12.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something on the lines of

```
$('[id$="socialSecurityNumber"]');
```

The $= means that the attribute ends with the specified string.

Comment: I never knew those types of selectors existed in jQuery. Learn something new everyday! +1!

Comment: There are also `|=` for contains prefix, `*=` for contains, `~=` for contains word, and `^=` for starts with

Answer (score 1):

Can you output the token to a javascript var and then use it for identifier?

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("ctl00_Spwebpartmanager1_g_0dff8583_314d_412f_8be7_ad019dd61cf3_ctl00__socialSecurityNumber")
```

If you want to do things with it using jQuery, you can do it like this:

```
$("#ctl00_Spwebpartmanager1_g_0dff8583_314d_412f_8be7_ad019dd61cf3_ctl00__socialSecurityNumber")
```